# Cannot find type definition file for 'bson'. The file is in the program because: Entry point for implicit type library 'bson'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint

I have setup new Typescript/React project, getting this error message in the tsconfig.json file

"Cannot find type definition file for 'bson'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'bson'"

any ideas.

here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Please post your tsconfig.json file and any other code which may be relevent

Comment: added it please have look.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the solution on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956#issuecomment-430849185)

> These errors occur when you have subdirectories of a typeRoots directory (in this case node_modules/@types) that do not contain index.d.ts

For me, the problem was because I was creating a library that did exported a bunch of `interfaces` & `types`

Here is an example

```
types-folder
├─── index.d.ts
└─── child-folder
     └─── index.d.ts // <-- Mandatory
```

Answer (score 19):

sometimes this is an eslint bug, try closing VSCODE and opening it again... It happened to me and I solved it that way.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly when encountering a similar issue, the only difference was a different module.  I restarted vscode, and the error reported against tsconfig.json disappeared!  @Shawn, the answer was perfectly sufficient to resolve my issue.  The "how" is... bug in eslint?

Comment: Solved mine by doing CTRL + SHIFT + P and then running Restart TS Server.

Answer (score 2):

Install it in your next js project

npm install --save-dev @types/json-schema

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I solved my problem with the above-given method. I just ran "npm install --save-dev @types/json-schema"

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have an empty `@types/` library declared in `package.json`, as explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27956#issuecomment-430849185).

In my case I had `"@types/": "react-navigation/native",` in `package.json`. This causes `react-navigation/native` to be installed directly in the `modules/@types` folder, which then causes this error.

I fixed it by removing `"@types/": "react-navigation/native",` from `package.json`, deleting the `node_modules` folder, reinstalling the libraries with `yarn install` and saving `tsconfig.json` (where the error was occurring).